# How to make Java executable fast?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an executable jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)

I want to distrubute my Java program to another person who wants to check out the software, but I don't want to reveal the code, until later if he requests it. How can I send my Java code + few xml files in a folder?

I've been thinking if jar is used for this purpose of distributing progrms. If so, Can it be used in my case? What are the other easy options?

Caveats: I don't have much time to spend. So i need something that can be done fast and is easy and no learning required. Also any links for steps-wise tutorial will be helpful

UPDATE: While making executable jar in Eclipse, is saying: Compile error.

Comment: "easy and no learning required" - lol!

Comment: "I don't want to reveal the code, until later if he requests it". This is essentially impossible. Java is fairly easily decompiled. You'll need either some degree of trust in your business relationship or demonstrate the software in person on a laptop you control. The moment you send a file, your source code (or a close approximation thereof) is revealed if the other side wants it badly enough.

Comment: Make your code obfscated

Answer (score 1):

No problem. You can make a JAR file with your IDE (e.g. Eclipse). Just click on export. You can include the source files, but you don't have to. You can also include your resources like a XML file.

You can also zip the compiled class files (e.g. your bin-folder in your IDE). But the JAR would be the better solution.

But test the JAR file before you send it. If it is your first time, there will properly be some problems like not founded resources or a missing main-class declaration in the manifest file. But if you using an IDE it should work in a minute.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans, I hope it'll work with that too

Comment: @user1174991 of course. That's a very basic task every IDE can do.

Comment: Eclipse while making executable jar files is saying: Compile error.

Comment: @user1174991 and does your project has compile errors? When you import it into Eclipse is something red? Btw, I thought you are using Netbeans?

Comment: There are no compile errors, just yellow warnings. I tried making jar as well as executable jar. Also the manifest file points to the correct main class

Comment: so, is there still any error<ß

Answer (score 0):

To make an executable jar file use command

jar -cvfe

To test if its working, just double click the jar. Be sure to include any libraries in the manifest.mf file.

Or you could just use your IDE to do the job for you.

Comment: What is written in the manifest file

Comment: A manifest file contains information about the jar. It has attributes like : Main-Class, Class-Path java version etc. Read this tutorial for more information : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html