# Creating java file to be executed by sh command

Tags: java, linux, execute

Hello I have a java program. I have a script that should execute the program. The script looks like this

```
sh compress.sh -f myfile.txt [-o myfile.hzip -s]
```

How do i create executable from my java program so that it can execute from this script?

Comment: Your question is poorly worded.  Are you asking how to execute this script from within a JAVA program?

Comment: What i mean to say is that this script should be able to execute my java program.

Comment: If I were you I would create a shell script with the corresponding java command.
For example:
javac myfile.java
java myfile

Comment: I think the question is not how to compile the source, but how to start the compiled program. I'd suggest making a jar and then putting something like "java my.jar my.package.main.class $1" ($1 for argument 1) into the shell script. Using eclipse, there is something like file->exportToJar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyApp.java:

```
public class MyApp {
   public static void main(String []args) {
        //Do something with args...
   }
}
```

compress.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Specify your Java class here (must contain a main method)
JAVA_CMD="java MyApp"

#JAR variant (a more common approach)
#JAVA_CMD="java -jar myjar.jar"

#Map script arguments to java app arguments. Use flag specific variables, if it's more convinient for you.
while getopts "f:o:s" opt; do
  case $opt in
    f)
      JAVA_CMD="$JAVA_CMD -f $OPTARG"
      ;;
    o)
      JAVA_CMD="$JAVA_CMD -o $OPTARG"
      ;;
    s)
      JAVA_CMD="$JAVA_CMD -s"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid usage..." >&2
      exit 1;
      ;;
  esac
done

#Additional validation (required options etc.)
#...

echo "Launching Java: $JAVA_CMD"
$JAVA_CMD
```

Compile your class, then run the script. You may be required to include [an additional classpath argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) in JAVA_CMD, if you're using any external libraries.

If you're going to use a JAR, then make sure, that your MANIFEST.mf has all the required information (especially a valid *Main-Class* entry). Further instructions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file).

If this is a Maven project, than you can create an executable JAR in one easy step using  [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Just run mvn assembly:assembly.

Comment: Ok I wrote a file called compress.sh with above script. But how do I pass the command line arguements to my java class ? for example              sh compress.sh -f myfile.txt [-o myfile.hzip -s]  i should be able to pass myfile.txt name to my java class

Comment: Command line arguments are accessible through the _args_ array in your main method. Executing java MyApp ABCD will result in args[0] == "ABCD". More examples can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).