# How to make a jar file as executable binary for linux and run as service

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, jar

I have a java jar file developed under Netbeans which I need to deploy in Linux. Now as per my requirement I have to make it as binary executable just like we get linux binaries to install and zip it under `.tar` extension so that user can install it from terminal.

Also I need to make it as linux daemon so that the application gets start as soon as the machine is turned on.

I am using Netbeans as development IDE and I need to install it under Linux Ubuntu machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an executable jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

An approach:

- [Create an executable JAR in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770791/1851024). Another option I prefer is to use Maven AppAssembler plugin. This is way more configurable and would give a quicker build, but will result into several JARs.
- Create an upstart script: [chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/11/18/running-a-jar-as-a-service-linuxupstart.html](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/11/18/running-a-jar-as-a-service-linuxupstart.html)