# How can I make a program executable by double clicking?

Tags: java

I wrote a JAVA program for my wife to compare coupons stacked with sales on different item sizes to save her time on her shopping-trip-planning.  Now I need to put it on her computer in such a way that she can double-click something, and have the program run.  I'm not finding anything good on the interwebs (like a decent step by step).

It is a simple program, one class with a nested class, and various imports of swing, awt, and text.

Since it's my wife's computer, I can make sure that she is running the appropriate JRE.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try to make executable jar file.?

Comment: Your question s OS specific: not the same on Linux than on Windows

Comment: create batch file and add it into window service

Comment: The first search result for "java tutorial executable jar" is [Java Tutorail: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/), the third is  [How to make an executable jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file), and that is not counting questions already shouwn as related.

Comment: Right, I read through all those, so I must be doing something wrong, then.  I get an executable jar, but when I double-click it, nothing happens.  If I change the "open with" to javaw, or javaws, I get a cmd window to flash on the screen, and as best I can tell is can't find the main class (disappears really quickly).  Must be a setting or option I don't have correct in the build process?

Comment: Looks like I get to choose between 2 "java platform (se) binary" to open the file, and one of them works fine.  Operational now.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) application. That convert executable `jar` file to `windows native executable` application.

You can also embed `JRE` with it so if `JRE` is not installed on machine the application will run.

you can also add some other mechanism to it also like loading image, icon, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Eclipse. In this website they given it very clearly for eclipse.

[Create Executable files in eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Export it to (or create a) executable Jar.

Most IDE's will do this (I think you have to dig around Eclipse a little) or take a look at [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) and [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) if you want to do it by hand

Most GUI OS's will run the Jar via a double click.

You could also investigate generating a native executable wrapper, which will make the program "look" more familiar to the user, including [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files) or [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) depending on your target platform

Answer (score 0):

Use NetBeans and simply 'Build' the jar file. This will produce an executable file within the 'dist' folder of your project.

Eclipse is the same however slightly more hidden.