# How to make runnable Jar programs that do not fail silently?

Tags: java, windows, deployment, error-handling, executable-jar

For the [runnable Jar programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587648/632951) I create, I can read the unhandled exceptions if I run it from the command prompt (`java -jar myprogram.jar`).

Example code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        EntireProgram();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new Error("somehow our error handling code has errors");
    }
}

public static void EntireProgram() {
    System.out.println(1 / 0);
}
```

Command line output:

[image]

However, if I run the Jar program **by double-clicking it** (expected of most end-users), the unhandled exceptions stay *silent*. I've noticed that this is in contrast to "native Windows programs" which I believe have unhandled exceptions handled by the OS default handler (modal dialog message):

[image]

[image]
[image]

The advantage of handling unhandled exceptions this way is that the user will **know** something wrong has happened (and perhaps report it, hopefully).

How can I make my program's unhandled exceptions be handled in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a single line like this in your catch block ..which will show you the error message irrespective of How you run your app.

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something is really wrong..Hence notifying you..");
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. I got stuck in a problem, where my `swing` based application requires `Java1.6` and above, but when I was executing that application in lower version of Java it was not showing anything, even I had given `showMessageDialog` in catch block, as there was error called `ClassNotFoundError`.

Comment: @user3505725, There *will* still be errors. We cannot expect code to be error-free, thus we cannot expect error-handling code (the showMessageDialog) to be error-free. How do we shift the responsibility of the error-handling to the OS?