# How to use MS Graph to automatic add Microsoft Teams tab for me in Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Currently I'm able to add tabs through Microsoft Graph but I wan't to kind of like set a date or time that my Microsoft Graph will automatically create a new tab inside my Microsoft Teams channel. Can someone please tell how I can achieve this in Java.

Comment: In **Java**? You'll need to show your research effort.

Comment: I saw this functions but I don't know how can I set a timer to let MSGraph add the tab by itself graphClient.teams(teamsId).channels(channelId).tabs().buildRequest().postAsync()

Comment: I went through the documentation in Microsoft Graph but can't seem to find anything related to my problem

Comment: Based on your requirement it seems like it is not feasible using Microsoft Graph . Alternatively what you can do is: you can build any background task or scheduler for triggering automatically at particular time and then can use Microsoft Graph to add tab.

Comment: Is there any documentation for me to have a look at the implementation example for java?

Comment: Could you please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818042/how-to-schedule-a-java-program-to-run-daily-in-windows)? It is in similar line.