# Multiple ways of creating executable jar not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a jar that the user can double-click to run (not a .exe just a jar that can be double-clicked). The problem is while this question has been asked many times none of the answers have worked.

I think the problem is not on my system, because other jar files on my system (that I didn't create) run fine. This makes me suspect I am doing something wrong.

First I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file) example.

However when I tried running the jar I made with that solution with:

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

I got the error: "no main manifest attribute in HelloWorld.jar"

I suspect the error is with my manifest file so here is is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.Main
```

I also tried:  "File --> Export --> RunnableJar" in eclipse but while that allowed me run to my jar from the command line when I tried double-clicking it I got the following message: "A Java Exception has occurred".

At this point, I don't know what to do to make my jar double-clickable.

What can I do to make my jar double-clickable?

Update: I used a new command:

```
jar cfe HelloWorld.jar main main.class
```

Now when I try to run this new jar from the command line with

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

I get the following error: "Could not find or load main class main"

Comment: Fix error caused by the exception.

Comment: Run it with java -jar HelloWorld.jar to know what the exception is, then fix it. If you have done that and it works, then it means the java version used when double-clicking is not the same as the one used from your command prompt.

Comment: Try this command - (Assuming your manifest file is named mani)

jar cfm HelloWorld.jar mani.mf *.class

Comment: @JBNizet The thing is, the jar file I made with eclipse works fine from the command line there is no exception. The exception only happens when I double-click the jar.

Answer (score 2):

If you did everything as described in that example, I think that there is no association with the `*.jar` file in the registry. Check it.

---

Also it maybe that two versions of Java installed.
Check Right-Click -> Open With. Java Runtime should be listed there.

Comment: How would I do that? Also I don't think the problem is with my system, after all other jar files made by different people are working fine when double-clicked.

Comment: I checked and it opens with: Java(TM) Platform SE Binary