# Jar file execution

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Suppose I made a program to take two input and display the sum.
It runs in netbeans but when I build out the jar file , and 
double clicked the jar file , nothing happens.
How can I make these program run?

Comment: Turn it into an executable jar

Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file

Comment: @Shloim that question is about swing, this here is about a consoleapp

Comment: I know, but it's the exact same set of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You must run this from command line, and then execute `java -jar {PATH_TO_JAR}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command-line :

```
java -jar <yourjar> <yourMainClass>
```

You can also add the main class in a manifest file into the jar. Doing so, you don't need to specify anymore on command line

Answer (score 0):

Jar files needs to run in JVM - Java Virtual machine, to run your file use:
"java -jar" and your jar.
By doing so, you tell Java to run your jar in jvm which means it now can run.