# Executable jar file created not getting executed

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have just made an executable jar file.But after being made,i found that it's not getting executed.I followed the instructions on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)  ,but then also its not getting executed.

Can someone help me out of this ??

Below is the output from console.

```
G:\javap>jar cvf t2.jar mn.mf TicTacToe.class
added manifest
adding: mn.mf(in = 44) (out= 46)(deflated -4%)
adding: TicTacToe.class(in = 6006) (out= 2543)(deflated 57%)
```

Comment: Creating it does not execute it.  Try `java -jar t2.jar`.

Comment: What i want to say that is,since i made an executable file,why isn't it  getting executed by double clicking the jar file??

Comment: You most likely have a broken Class-Path entry in Manifest.MF.  Try the manual invocation frist.

Comment: can we see the manifest??

Comment: Manifest Version: 1.0
Main-Class: TicTacToe

Comment: @Xoce ,This is the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either specify the 'm' flag AND the name of the manifest file that contains `Main-Class:` (possibly among other things), OR the 'e' flag AND the name of the class and `jar` creates a manifest for you containing that `Main-Class:` The [linked dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258323/2868801) does the former; notice `cfm` in its flags.

```
jar cfm t2.jar mn.mf TicTacToe.class
jar cfe t2.jar TicTacToe TicTacToe.class 
rem add v flag if you wish, it doesn't affect the jar
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html#sthref40 .