# Java Rest Client using Jersey from Command Line

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jar, jersey-2.0

I am trying to create a Java Rest Client which will download a file via a get request and will use basic authentication.
I have a dynamic web project in eclipse, where i put the Jersey Jars downloaded from https://jersey.java.net/download.html into the web-inf>lib folder.

- Q1 - Eclipse is not able to identify package javax.ws.rs.* and
  shows compilation errors.
- Q2-  I want to package this as a Jar(I have a main class) and want to
  execute it from command line. Is it possible ? If not how can I do
  this.

Update: Below is the screenshot of what I have done till now . 
I am not sure if I am using the correct Jar Files .

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Comment: Please would you explain your problem a little bit more. Show us your research results.

Comment: I see two questions here. 1) How include a jar in eclipse?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: 2) How package an executable jar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

Your Jersey Jar files does not contain the Client, ClientBuilder and Response classes. They are available here [www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.ws/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar.zip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.ws/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar.zip). Download and use it. You need to import `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` also in your code. You can generate a runnable JAR file and execute it.