# Possibility Standalone application for JMS/MQ messaging?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I want to create a Java standalone application it should be an .exe and install it in the local machine for connecting via JMS to a client Queue Manager. 
Example: The scenario is like the project should be developed to connect to active 
MQ client queue from the local machine connecting via JMS. If i put a message in the application it should connect to client Queue through QCF in a standalone application without installing in WebSphere server.

Is there way to implement or any example that I can take to build this project?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a whole bunch of stand-alone JMS/MQ sample applications [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html#jmscode) but really this not an JMS/MQ question but rather a Java question.  You have 3 choices:

1. Executable JAR file
2. Use a tool that will bundle your JAR files into an 'exe'
3. Use [Excelsior JET](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

If you are looking to protect your code from being decompiled then your only choice is Excelsior JET.

Note: The cheap way might be to use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) with option #2.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create an [executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file). If you are maven oriented, the [Shaded](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin makes fairly short work of this. However, the WebsphereMQ jars do not support relocation (i.e. moving them around from their original installation location) with the exception of the JMS RAR (which is not applicable to your non Java EE app) and the new MQ8 relocatable jar file called [com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376217).

As far as creating an actual **exe**, there are ways of doing this like [InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installanywhere/), but an executable jar is probably simpler.