# Export jar from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hello iI'm trying to export my program from intellij, I do this in this way
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/ 
but this jar works only on Windows, but I want to open this also on MacOs.

Comment: jar  files are cross-platform... What happens when you open the file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891, jars will work on any platform unless there is an issue with your code which depends on the OS.

Comment: yes jar files should work on different platform. When I want to open it on Macos I get error. I tried open Scene builder from gluon, there are two different jars executable and normal, normal I cannot open on mac but I can open executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

If jar is not executable, then there is no Main class specified in Manifest.mf file. Java doesn't know what you want to run.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258323/8886141

Comment: How would you explain that it reportedly works on Windows?