# how to run .jar files on Synology

Tags: java, jar, synology, war

for a Synology NAS DS118 i want to run a jar file and i'm looking for a way to hibernate the program on the synology so that it executes automatically, can anyone help ?
i have tried to run the .jar from the ssh client but i think i should first make the jar file executable and i still didn't figure it out...i couldn't find any detailed tutorials yet :( –

Comment: You may want to provide more information such as solutions attempted or research conducted.

Comment: sorry, i'm a bit of a newbie to Synology NAS, i have tried to run the .jar from the ssh client but i think i should first make the jar file executable and i still didn't figure it out...i couldn't find any detailed tutorials yet :(

Comment: add this comment to your question

Answer (score 3):

You have to installed and updated the Oracle Java package. You have to also enable terminal access to the NAS and navigated to the right directory where the jar file is. I am not aware of your specific package, but i assume since you can start the foo.jar via double click you might also be able to start this foo.jar on your DiskStation like this :

ssh -ladmin YOURDISKSTATIONIP
YOUR_ADMINPASSWORD

cd TOYOURJARDIRECTORY

java -jar foo.jar

where foo.jar is the .jar you want to start. 
You can write a bash service and it gonna be automatized. I hope it will be helpful for you.

To make your java file executable. See this post;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209860/5879876

Comment: I have already installed the Java packages and enable client access to the NAS. the Java package is Java8,