# manifest error, Error: Could not find or load main class test.Class1

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have three classes, all in the same package. I just need the execption when I run,
**java -jar jarName.jar**

**Class1.java**

```
package test;

public class Class1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
       {

     System.out.println("Enter Class1");
     //Class1 bs = new Class1();

     Class2 objClass2 = new Class2();
     objClass2.method1();

     System.out.println("Exit Class1");
   }
 //hello
```

}

**Class2.java**

```
package test;

public class Class2 {

    int exitValue=100;

    public static int doIt() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Enter doIt");
        int exitValue=10;
        if(exitValue>0) {
            throw new TestInstallException("Got an Exception here!");
        }       

    return 0;
}

public void method1() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Enter Class2");
    int exitValue = Class2.doIt();
    System.exit(exitValue); 
}
```

}

**TestInstallException.java**

```
package test;

public class TestInstallException extends java.lang.Exception {

    public TestInstallException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public TestInstallException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

public TestInstallException(String s, Exception e) {
    super(s, e);
}

public TestInstallException(Throwable cause)
{
    super(cause);
}
```

}

I even modified the manifest file with the below content,

**>cat dd/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**
Manifest-Version: 1.0 .
Created-By: 1.8.0_141 (Oracle Corporation) .
**Main-Class: test.Class1** .

So, as we can see it has the main class defined. I bundled everthing in a jar file called new.jar. But, when I run java -jar new.jar, I get below exception.

**java -jar new.jar**
**Error: Could not find or load main class test.Class1**

jar -tvf test.jar
     0 Sat Apr 14 20:17:54 IST 2018 META-INF/ .
    89 Sat Apr 14 20:29:48 IST 2018 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
   562 Sat Apr 14 20:11:02 IST 2018 Class1.class .
   760 Sat Apr 14 20:11:06 IST 2018 Class2.class .
   542 Sat Apr 14 20:10:50 IST 2018 TestInstallException.class .

Comment: I am able to run this from eclipse, and also using the java test.Class1. However, want to run this as jar file.

Comment: can you please manage your code , so that it became easy to read, also put above comment in question.

Comment: Did you include the proper args in your cmd when creating your jar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file

Comment: Inspect the output of new.jar. `jar -tvf new.jar`

Comment: Post the output of the command. We have no way of knowing if your expectations are correct.

Comment: added the jar -tvf in the first post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, by bundling the class inside the test folder.

test/Class*.class

Also, added this in the manifest
Class-Path: .