# Accessing an entity of a project in another

Tags: java, class

Let's say I have `JProjectOne` and `JProjectTwo`. Will the public class I have in `JProjectOne` be visible in `JProjectTwo` or do I have to do some tweaking for it to be visible?

Comment: "Projects" are not a concept that the Java Language knows about - that's just your IDE doing things its way. Before Java9, public classes were visible to any other class. Since Java9, with modules, there are some changes to that.

Comment: As long, as JProjectTwo doesn't have JProjectOne in its classpath, nothing from the latter is accessible to the former

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the place where `JAR`s come handy, make a jar file of the public class you want in other project. Then add it to present project.

1. **Creating a JAR** - [How to make an executable jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)
2. **How to add external JARs to a project** - [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

**private** hides from other classes within the package. **public** exposes to classes outside the package. A **protected** member is accessible within all classes in the same package and within sub classes in other packages.
May be [JAVA Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Arun suggested try with jar, but if You are using Maven, that is quiet easy to do that, here is an example:

Here is how You could "install", send you jar file to .m2 (maven container),

```
mvn install:install-file
   -Dfile=<path-to-file>
   -DgroupId=<group-id>
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
   -Dversion=<version>
   -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   -DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
   <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
   <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
   <version>       the version of the file
   <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

so this is how would this look like (example):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\test_0.0.1.jar -DgroupId= com.test
-DartifactId=project -Dversion=0.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

...and simply calling in other project like this (also from maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

and just do always pom.xml import on file, to update it and You're good to go. This is just local jar importing.

Hope this helps.