# Can we create standalone exe files from sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

Sikuli involves both Java and Python.
You can find Sikuli here: http://www.sikuli.org/
Question:
Can we create an exe file from sikuli? 
Having a folder that includes screen captured pieces, along with the exe file is not a problem.

Even a simple double click program on something on screen would do as a sample program and sikuli doesn't support actual code standalone, it creates files of course (including one in python)

My worktime has ended so I will be afk, so give me some time till I will reach home to reply on any questions that might arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an executable using either, Java or Python. In case of Java, you can [create an executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file) and in case of Python you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) utility.