# Kotlin: How to create a runnable jar?

Tags: kotlin, jar

I'm trying to create a runnable jar with Kotlin.

My gradle.build is this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'

}

group 'com.github.dynamik'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
mainClassName = "interpreter.Repl"





repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/hotkeytlt/maven") }

}
configurations {
    ktlint
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile 'com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse-jvm:0.4.0-alpha-3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    ktlint "com.github.shyiko:ktlint:0.31.0"




    implementation 'com.github.ajalt:clikt:1.7.0'


    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.0'



}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'interpreter.Repl'
    }
}
```

(As it stands, when I do `./gradlew run`, everything works as expected.)

I'm reading an article [here](https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/kotlin-basics-create-executable-kotlin-jars-using-gradle-d17e9a8384b9)  on how to proceed, and it says to do: `java -jar <MY_PROJECT_NAME>.jar`.

I don't quite understand this -- **where do we run this**? I tried running it from my project root and I got an error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile <my_jarname>.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out :)

So, the way to create a jar is to go: `./gradlew build`. This creates a jar in `build/libs`.

The problem is, when running that jar, one would run into an exception about `java.lang.intrinsics` because the `kotlin stdlib` hasn't been packed into the jar.

While there is a way to manually accomplish that, I found the easiest solution is to simply use the `shadowjar plugin`.

My build.gradle ended up looking like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.4'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'

}

group 'com.github.dynamik'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'


mainClassName = "interpreter.Repl"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/hotkeytlt/maven") }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }

}
configurations {
    ktlint
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile 'com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse-jvm:0.4.0-alpha-3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    ktlint "com.github.shyiko:ktlint:0.31.0"
    implementation 'com.github.ajalt:clikt:1.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'



compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'interpreter.Repl'
    }
}
```

Comment: how to execute kotlin jar file , some where is studied jar file is not executable for kotlin . Please guide me.

Comment: > Plugin with id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' not found.

Answer (score 5):

As of Gradle 5.4.1, a `build.gradle.kts` would need a section like this:

```
tasks.register<Jar>("uberJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("uber")

    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class" to "mytest.AppKt",
                "Implementation-Title" to "Gradle",
                "Implementation-Version" to archiveVersion
        )
    }

    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When using a Kotlin main class you need to add a `Kt` at the end of the class name while referencing it on MANIFEST.
So, if your main class is called `interpreter.Repl`, use:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'interpreter.ReplKt'
    }
}
```

instead of

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'interpreter.Repl'
    }
}
```

Comment: You would also need to pack kotlin sdtlib within your generated .jar.

Comment: thank you for the pointers! Just a quick question though: how is that ```java -jar <MY_PROJECT_NAME>.jar``` command supposed to be run? I'm looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file and it seems like it has to point to .class files in java - is it the same with kotlin?

Comment: When using `-jar` you will need to point to a .jar file. In your case, your generated .jar.
It's supposed to execute the jar exactly as your IDE do. If you don't print anything you will have no output on `java -jar xxx.jar`

Comment: cool, thanks! I guess I need to first figure out how to create the .jar file.