# IntelliJ generated jar artifact doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I've recently finished my project and now I would like to build the artifact for it.
During the process I've followed the guide provided by jetbrains which can be found here:

> https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

I've done everything step by step as the guide says but when I run the actual jar file it doesn't do anything.

Could any of you help me identify the problem please?

[image: -]

The manifest was generated by the IDE automatically and has inside the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: application.Main
```

This is how the jar file looks like inside:
[image]

Also I would like to mention that no errors occurred during building the artifact.

Comment: How do you run it? Any errors you get? Did you create manifest file with the main class to run? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258323/2000323) is how you can first try to create a simple jar and run it.

Comment: I've updated the question @GhostCat

Comment: 2 years and 11 months later I am suffering from the same fate and have no clue what is wrong. Navigating to the folder where my main class is and running `java -cp <semicolon-separated list of paths to used jar files> main" (I have a Scala 3 project) works fine, however.