# Application runs fine in Intellij but doesn't work when packaged into an exe file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, launch4j, picocli

I have built a very simple command line application using [picocli](https://picocli.info) and I would like to package it into an executable file. I first packaged it into a `jar` file using Maven package, and then used [Launch4J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/) as recommended by several users on SO to  obtain an executable. However, it throws the NoClassDefFound error, when I run `Application.exe` in the command prompt.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> picocli/CommandLine                                                 
> at mycli.HelloCli.main(HelloCli.java:48)                              
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: picocli.CommandLine      
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)                  
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)                    
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)         
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)                    
> ... 1 more
```

The application works perfectly well when executed in IntelliJ. I tried adding the custom jar file I created by looking at answers similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) but it doesn't seem to help. I also tried changing the folder of execution but that doesn't solve the error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From several answers I searched across SO, I realized that the picocli jar needed to be on the class path. So I added the "Main class" as the one containing my `main` method, and specified the "Classpath" to the `jar` file created by building an artifact out of all the dependencies present, while configuring Launch4J.

For details on how to build an artifact jar out of a project's dependencies, visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file) if you use Eclipse, or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) if you use IntelliJ.)

[image: Launch4J configuration window]