# JAR Command not using supplied Manifest

Tags: java, manifest, executable-jar

Unsure why I am getting this error, I feel that I am missing something very simple. This is an issue I am facing trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file) post on creating a JAR executable from the command line. Here are my simple test files:

JarExample.java:

```
public class JarExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JarExample
```

I run the follow commands to construct the JAR:

```
javac JarExample.java
jar cfm JarExample.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class
```

Yet when I run `java -jar JarExample.jar`, I get the following error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in JarExample.jar
```

Peaking inside the JAR, the correct class file is present, but the following autogenerated manifest, `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, is present:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation)
```

So where is my usage of the `jar` command incorrect? Why does it not recognize my supplied manifest file?

Thanks!

Comment: It’s hard to retrace your issue as whatever the problem causes is likely not present in our systems or may unconsciously be avoided by us. You can use the `v` option to get more diagnostic output. Note that for just setting the main class, you don’t need to deal with the manifest at all. You can use `jar cfe JarExample.jar JarExample *.class` to set the **e**ntry point aka main class to `JarExample`. And use `jar vcfe JarExample.jar JarExample *.class` to get the **v**erbose output.

Comment: This link should help -> [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have followed all steps that you described, and an executable jar file has been successfully created.

I'm using `openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20`

The generated file inside the .jar file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JarExample
Created-By: 11.0.11 (Ubuntu)
```

So this is may be caused by your Java version or used Operation System.

In the referenced by you answer, there is [a useful comment by David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file#comment96882376_5258323):

> If you create the MANIFEST.MF file, **don't forget to finish the last line
> with a line break.** On Windows just add an empty line at the end.
> Otherwise the last attribute will not make it in the jar file. In this
> special case the Main-Class attribute will be missing.

Probably, this is your case. Because when I remove the last line break in the `MANIFEST.MF`, I'm getting the same error as yours:

> no main manifest attribute, in JarExample.jar

Example of `MANIFEST.MF` with the last line break (3rd line is empty) - works well

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JarExample
```

Without the last line break (2 lines of code) - crashes with an error

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JarExample
```

Comment: Ah, right you are! I missed that comment. What an odd requirement.